# How do I return the next available date from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table (`dates`):

```
_date
------------
2011-03-14
2011-03-15
2011-03-16
2011-03-19
2011-03-20
2011-03-22
2011-03-23
```

With what query can I return the first date in `dates` following any given date? Pseudo:

```
SELECT <<nextdate>> FROM dates WHERE _date = '2011-03-14'
```

This query would have to return `2011-03-15`, since it is the first date in `dates` after `2011-03-15`. But when querying the following:

```
SELECT <<nextdate>> FROM dates WHERE _date = '2011-03-16'
```

Then the query should return `2011-03-19`, as it is the first date in `dates` after `2011-03-16`.

Who can help me our here? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  SELECT _date
    FROM dates
   WHERE _date > '2011-03-14'
ORDER BY _date
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I would not have thought of that...so simple! I was already looking at MySQL date-functions...thank!